# Custom Bubble Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to understand what is wrong with my code, I am a beginner in C however, i programmed extensively in java. I made my own "lazy" implementation for bubble sort using 8 integers ,however it results in an infinite loop.

some explanation: attempting to sort 8 integers largest to smallest and using the counter to determine when all the values are sorted

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int array[8];
int counter =0;
int storage=0;
int i;
printf("Please enter 8 numbers:");
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&array[0],&array[1],&array[2],&array[3],&array[4],&array[5],&array[6],&array[7]);
while (counter!=7)
{
    counter =0;
for (i=0; i<=6;i++)
{
    if (array[i]<=array[i++])
    {
        storage = array[i];
        array[i]= array[i++];
        array[i++]= storage;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
}
printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5],array[6],array[7]);
```

}

Comment: `array[i]` will always equal to  `array[i++]`. Perhaps you meant `array[++i]`?

Comment: When attaining you extensive Java experience, did you ever do any debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the following piece of code from:

```
if (array[i]<=array[i++])
{
    storage = array[i];
    array[i]= array[i++];
    array[i++]= storage;
}
```

To

```
if (array[i]<array[i+1])//++ is post increment operator and you are changing index value with every comparison and assignment
{
    storage = array[i];
    array[i]= array[i+1];
    array[i+1]= storage;
}
```

Also reason for infinite loop is when you swap two elements you dont increment the value of counter. So you should remove it from else part and make it common in for loop irrespective of whether you swap two elements or not. Or you could have `while (counter != 0) {counter = 0; ...}` So its like modifies bubble sort.

Comment: `array[i]<=array[i++]` has undefined behavior.

Comment: basically it means `array[i]<=array[i] then i=i+1` so why undefined?

Comment: the first subscript  `i` is it the old or the new one ? @almasshaikh

Comment: @Meninx so its like comparing the same number, same subscript and it would always satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you, the +1 worked, i need o read up on the ++ operator in c. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

switch this incorrect if block

```
if (array[i]<=array[i++])
{
    storage = array[i];
    array[i]= array[i++];
    array[i++]= storage;
}
```

by this block if you want an **ascending order**

```
if (array[i]>array[i+1])
{
    storage = array[i];
    array[i]= array[i+1];
    array[i+1]= storage;
}
```

or by this below if you want a **descending order**  (please note the if condition)

```
if (array[i]<array[i+1])
{
    storage = array[i];
    array[i]= array[i+1];
    array[i+1]= storage;
}
```

and change the last `printf()` in order to get a correct and readable output by adding spaces between integers

```
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5],array[6],array[7]);
```